# Complex xml into Tabular format using XSLT Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

My requirement is to convert a complex XML data into tabular format using XSLT transformation.I am able to design an XSLT but I am getting multiple rows for each repeated field like Department and Center.In one row I am getting the values for DepartmentCode and DepartmentName with CenterCode and CenterName as NULL and in the other row I am getting the values for CenterCode and CenterName with DepartmentCode and DepartmentName as NULL.Please help,me in designing XSLT for the below complex XML file.

Complex XML File

```
 <Report_Data>
  <Report_Entry> 
   <EmployeeID>78798</EmployeeID>
   <ActiveDirectoyID>sanjeev@hotmail.com</ActiveDirectoyID> 
   <PlatinumID>7598409</PlatinumID>
   <LastName>Paul</LastName>
   <Department>
    <DepartmentCode>601</DepartmentCode>
    <DepartmentName>Service</DepartmentName>
   </Department> 
   <Department>
    <DepartmentCode>602</DepartmentCode>
    <DepartmentName>Mgmt</DepartmentName>
   </Department>   
   <Center>
    <CenterCode>101</CenterCode>
    <CenterName>ABC</CenterName>
   </Center>
   <Center>
    <CenterCode>102</CenterCode>
    <CenterName>PQR</CenterName>
   </Center>
   <BusinessUnit>Sample</BusinessUnit>
   <BankAccountType>1001</BankAccountType>
 </Report_Entry>
 </Report_Data>
```

XSLT Code

```
    <xslt:stylesheet xmlns:xslt="http://www.abc.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pqr-           xform="http://www.testing.com/2003/xform"                                                               xmlns:xs="http://www.abc.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
   <xslt:template match="/">
   <xslt:variable name="_EmployeeID"/>
   <xslt:variable name="_DepartmentCode"/>
   <xslt:variable name="_DepartmentName"/>
   <xslt:variable name="_CenterCode"/>
   <xslt:variable name="_CenterName"/>
   <xslt:element name="results">
    <xslt:for-each select="Report_Data">
    <xslt:for-each select="Report_Entry">
      <xslt:variable name="_EmployeeID" select="EmployeeID"/>
      <xslt:for-each select="Department">
        <xslt:variable name="_DepartmentCode" select="DepartmentCode"/>
        <xslt:variable name="_DepartmentName" select="DepartmentName"/>
        <xslt:element name="result">
          <xslt:element name="EmployeeID">
            <xslt:value-of select="$_EmployeeID"/>
          </xslt:element>
          <xslt:element name="DepartmentCode">
            <xslt:value-of select="$_DepartmentCode"/>
          </xslt:element>
          <xslt:element name="DepartmentName">
            <xslt:value-of select="$_DepartmentName"/>
          </xslt:element>
          <xslt:element name="CenterCode">
            <xslt:value-of select="$_CenterCode"/>
          </xslt:element>
          <xslt:element name="CenterName">
            <xslt:value-of select="$_CenterName"/>
          </xslt:element>
        </xslt:element>
        </xslt:for-each>
        <xslt:for-each select="Center">
        <xslt:variable name="_CenterCode" select="CenterCode"/>
        <xslt:variable name="_CenterName" select="CenterName"/>
        <xslt:element name="result">
          <xslt:element name="EmployeeID">
            <xslt:value-of select="$_EmployeeID"/>
          </xslt:element>
          <xslt:element name="DepartmentCode">
            <xslt:value-of select="$_DepartmentCode"/>
          </xslt:element>
          <xslt:element name="DepartmentName">
            <xslt:value-of select="$_DepartmentName"/>
          </xslt:element>
          <xslt:element name="CenterCode">
            <xslt:value-of select="$_CenterCode"/>
          </xslt:element>
          <xslt:element name="CenterName">
            <xslt:value-of select="$_CenterName"/>
          </xslt:element>
        </xslt:element>
        </xslt:for-each>
        <xslt:element name="result">
        <xslt:element name="EmployeeID">
          <xslt:value-of select="$_EmployeeID"/>
        </xslt:element>
        <xslt:element name="DepartmentCode">
          <xslt:value-of select="$_DepartmentCode"/>
        </xslt:element>
        <xslt:element name="DepartmentName">
          <xslt:value-of select="$_DepartmentName"/>
        </xslt:element>
        <xslt:element name="CenterCode">
          <xslt:value-of select="$_CenterCode"/>
        </xslt:element>
        <xslt:element name="CenterName">
          <xslt:value-of select="$_CenterName"/>
        </xslt:element>
        </xslt:element>
        </xslt:for-each>
        </xslt:for-each>
        </xslt:element>
        </xslt:template>
        </xslt:stylesheet>
```

Required Output

EmployeeID  DepartmentCode  DepartmentName  CenterCode  CenterName
78798                 601               Service              101                ABC
78798                 602               Mgmt                 102                PQR

Thanks and Regards
Sanjeev

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I can only able to design a simple XSLT which can fetch me records in multiple rows for Department and Center.

Comment: I have a tool where I can map the columns to the output columns and the XSLT gets created automatically but only for simple XML not for complex XMLs like this.In case of custom XML the tool allows to customise the XSLT to get the desired output.

Comment: Without seeing your xslt or a snippet of the relevant xslt code, its hard to help you.

Comment: I have added the XSLT code,please have a look and let me know what chnages I have to do in the XSLT in order to have single row for each Department and Center with all the columns values.

Comment: You seem to think that you can change values of XSLT variables. This is not the case. All XSLT variables are read-only.

Comment: Also, you did not explain *at all* what your expected output should look like. That's kind of essential info...

Comment: I see no connection between the required output and the attempted stylesheet. Moreover, the stylesheet can **not** produce the result stated in the question ("I am getting multiple rows for each repeated field like Department and Center.") because (1) it contains an invalid namespace for the stylesheet declaration itself - so it cannot run at all, and (2) if corrected, the output is XML with no "rows".

Answer (score 1):

Possible cause of the problem: If this is an XSLT 1.0 processor, please be aware that assigning the result of a select to a variable produces a Result Tree Fragment. These can not be navigated directly. There is a helper function in the EXSLT collection, implemented by most XSLT processors which will convert Result Tree Fragments to Nodesets, which can then be further explored.

http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/

(If you are using XSLT 2.0, Result Tree Fragments and Node Sets were combined into a single concept, Temporary Trees, and the conversion is not necessary.)

ADDED:

Actually, the easiest way to get rid of that problem is to get rid of the variables entirely. And while you're at it, restructure the stylesheet as a proper rule system, using templates to describe "when you see this, do that". In most cases, if you're using xsl:for-each, you're making your XSLT more difficult than it should be.

Also, using literal result elements will make the XSLT far more readable. You shouldn't need xsl:element unless you have to programmatically construct the name and namespace of an element at runtime.

ADDED:

You've also got what looks like some superfluous logic at the end of your template. Another advantage to the rule-based approach is that, like subroutines, it breaks your code up into chunks which are easier to read and verify.

ADDED:

It would help tremendously if you'd showed us what output you actually expected. Without that, I'm trying to guess your intent from your code despite its bugs.

This may come close; if not, it should at least give you some idea of how a more experienced stylesheet author would approach the problem. WARNING: UNTESTED.

```
<xslt:stylesheet xmlns:xslt="http://www.abc.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xslt:template match="/">
<results>
  <xslt:apply-templates select="Report_Data"/>
</results>
  </xslt:template>

  <xslt:template match="Report_Data">
<xslt:apply-templates select="/Report_Data/Report_Entry>"/>
  </xslt:template>

  <xslt:template match="Report_Entry">
<result>
  <xslt:apply-templates select="Department"/>
  <xslt:apply-templates select="Center"/>
</result>
  </xslt:template>

  <xslt:template match="Department">
<EmployeeId><xsl:value-of select="../EmployeeId"/></EmployeeId>
<xsl:copy-of select="DepartmentCode"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="DepartmentName"/>
  </xslt:template>

  <xslt:template match="Center">
<EmployeeId><xsl:value-of select="../EmployeeId"/></EmployeeId>
<xsl:copy-of select="CenterCode"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="CenterName"/>
  </xslt:template>

</xslt:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you please provide me one example using my xml data attached,it will really be helpful.

Comment: My output should have multiple rows for each DepartmentCode and DEpartmentName and all the columns also should have values corresponding to it in tabular format.I have attached the required output format.